# Octave-4.2.1 fails in trivial plotting example

Tags: octave

I am trying run a [trivial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Octave_Programming_Tutorial/Getting_started) octave example. I am running octave-4.2.1 on CentOS 6.6

When I run :

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
y = sin(x);
plot(x, y);
```

Octave unexpectedly terminates when I enter the `plot(x,y)` command with

```
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
```

I think I have correctly set GNUTERM:

```
>> getenv("GNUTERM")
ans = X11
```

If I run:

```
>> graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")
error: graphics_toolkit: gnuplot version too old.
error: called from
    graphics_toolkit at line 88 column 9
```

QUESTION : How do I resolve this problem with octave-4.2.1?  Is this related to gnuplot being too old?

Comment: Have you tried updating gnuplot for your system?  https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-i386/gnuplot-4.2.6-2.el6.i686.rpm.html

Comment: I am currently running gnuplot 4.4

Comment: Sure? as far as I can see on CentOS 6.6, it's 4.2.6

Comment: and the error "graphics_toolkit: gnuplot version too old." is shown if the gnuplot version is < 4.4 (which is too old as the message already said)

Comment: Ok, you are correct.  `/usr/bin/gnuplot --version == gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6`.  I had aliased `gnuplot` in my local environment to `/usr/bin/gnuplot44`.

Comment: When I set `graphics_toolkit("fltk")` and then `plot(x,y)` I get  a pop up window and an error `libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast`.  Reading further, it seems that opengl is by default the backend  http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Why_did_you_replace_Gnuplot_with_an_OpenGL_backend.3F     Maybe this is a problem with openGL?

Comment: you can use `gnuplot_binary("/usr/gin/gnuplot44")` to point to the alternative gnuplot binary